# How to connect a function to mapStateToProps?

Tags: redux, react-redux

I try to connect a function that is not a component to mapStateToProps using React Redux connect().
The goal is to access redux state outside of the component. 
But once i try to run the function connectedJob() nothing happens.

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    user: state.user
  };
};

const job = ({user}) => console.log(user.id);

const connectedJob = connect(mapStateToProps)(job);

connectedJob(); //undefined
```

Comment: what you expecting with connectedJob(), connectedJob should be a react component you can't use it like this.... just export.default connect(mapStateToProps)(component), when you recieve props into redux then you will get state value here....

Comment: I'd like to use state.user outside of component, in an external function like job(). So it is not possible to use connect on functions that are not component ?

Comment: Connect requires react component in returned function call as per docs https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect. So you can't do that if you tell me actual thing what you want to do then we can crack your problem.

Comment: Thank you. I imported the store and used store.getState().user instead for accessing the user